# Indentação com problemas no Studio

Tags: android-studio, indentação

Estou apanhando muito com indentação de código no *Android Studio*. Meu código está muito feio como mostra a imagem e eu não consigo indentá-lo. Já mudei o *keymap* para eclipse, netbeans e parece que nada resolve.

- Alguém pode me ajudar em como devo proceder ?
- Além disso, é possível colocar os atalhos do eclipse nele ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Windows:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Linux:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Mac:

> <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: Queira por favor explicar o que esses "comandos" fazem.

Comment: Identa o codigo.

Comment: Não funciona também.

Comment: Ajusta seu android studio para valores padroes e testa